# how to remove double quotes out side of generated json from string list using python

Tags: json, python-3.x

My JSON is
imput json
{ 'debug': None,
'traceback': None,
'rsname': None,
'resolutionStatus': 0,
'algorithmResponseInfo': None,
'rules': "['check']",
'rulesResults':
'-RNCID Found',
'mmlCommand': 'tk_com',
'KMmmlCommand': 'cat "tk"',
'similarityScore': {'similarityUI': 100 }}
which is invalid and I want to convert it into valid json
I want to remove `""` double quotes and single backslash from rules column (list) using python.
I have already tried the following but it didn't work -

```
data = data.replace('"',"\\'").replace("'", '"').replace("True","true").\
             replace("None","null").replace("False","false").replace("\'", '"').replace("'", '"')

data = json.loads(data)
```

output is -
data = {
"debug": null,
"traceback": null,
"rsname": null,
"resolutionStatus": 0,
"algorithmResponseInfo": null,
"rules": \ "["check"]",
"rulesResults": "-RNCID Found",
"mmlCommand": "tk_com",
"KMmmlCommand": "cat "tk"",
"similarityScore": {
"similarityUI": 100
}}

but i need to remove extra backshlash and double quotes
expected is -
data = {
"debug": null,
"traceback": null,
"rsname": null,
"resolutionStatus": 0,
"algorithmResponseInfo": null,
"rules": ["check"],
"rulesResults": "-RNCID Found",
"mmlCommand": "tk_com",
"KMmmlCommand": "cat "tk"",
"similarityScore": {
"similarityUI": 100
}}

Comment: It seems you replacing all of the (") in this line -> data.replace('"',"\\'") ,help us help you and attach the result after the replace

Comment: my input -     'output\': {
  \'debug\': None,
  \'traceback\': None,
  \'rsname\': None, 
  \'resolutionStatus\': 0, 
  \'algorithmResponseInfo\': None, 
  \'rules\': "[\'check\']",
  \'rulesResults\': \'-RNCID Found\',
  \'mmlCommand\': \'tk_com\',
  \'KMmmlCommand\': \'cat "tk"\',
  \'similarityScore\': 
  {\'similarityUI\': 100
  }}

Comment: after applying     data = data.replace('"',"\\'").replace("'", '"').replace("True","true").\
         replace("None","null").replace("False","false").replace("\'", '"').replace("'", '"')   got    "output": {
  "debug": null,
  "traceback": null,
  "rsname": null,
  "resolutionStatus": 0,
  "algorithmResponseInfo": null,
  "rules": \ "["check"]\",
  "rulesResults": "-RNCID Found",
  "mmlCommand": "tk_com",
  "KMmmlCommand": "cat \"tk\"",
  "similarityScore": {
   "similarityUI": 100
  }}     i want to clear json  due to rule : \ "["check"]\"  i am not able to do json.loads()

Comment: backslash and double quotes are added extra on rules

Comment: Please edit the question with the input/output

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is not JSON at all, but a Python literal.  It's just that Python's literals are very similar to JSON.  The safe way to convert this is using ast.literal_eval:

```
from ast import literal_eval
import json
data = (
    "{ 'debug': None, 'traceback': None, 'rsname': None,"
    " 'resolutionStatus': 0, 'algorithmResponseInfo': None, "
    "'rules': \"['check']\", 'rulesResults': '-RNCID Found', "
    "'mmlCommand': 'tk_com', 'KMmmlCommand': 'cat \"tk\"',"
    " 'similarityScore': {'similarityUI': 100 }}"
python_doc = literal_eval(data)
json_str = json.dumps(python_doc)

# {"debug": null, "traceback": null, "rsname": null, "resolutionStatus": 0,
# "algorithmResponseInfo": null, "rules": "['check']",
#  "rulesResults": "-RNCID Found", "mmlCommand": "tk_com",
#  "KMmmlCommand": "cat \"tk\"", "similarityScore": {"similarityUI": 100}}
print(json_str)
```

The unsafe alternative to `literal_eval` is `eval`.  The problem with `eval` is that if an attacker can control the input, they can cause arbitrary code to run.

Comment: this is the output

Comment: "{ 'debug': None, 'traceback': None, 'rsname': None, 'resolutionStatus': 0, 'algorithmResponseInfo': None, 'rules': \"['check']\", 'rulesResults': '-RNCID Found', 'mmlCommand': 'tk_com', 'KMmmlCommand': 'cat \"tk\"', 'similarityScore': {'similarityUI': 100 }}"    i need to  output in purely json

Comment: i have added -     data = json.loads(json_str)
    data = data.replace('"', "\\'").replace("'", '"').replace("None","null")
    print(data)  out put is - { "debug": null, "traceback": null, "rsname": null, "resolutionStatus": 0, "algorithmResponseInfo": null, "rules": \"["check"]\", "rulesResults": "-RNCID Found", "mmlCommand": "tk_com", "KMmmlCommand": "cat \"tk\"", "similarityScore": {"similarityUI": 100 }}      why "rules" :  \"["check"]\"    how can i avoid it extra  backshlash and  double quotes

Comment: In my example, after literal_eval, the data is in python_doc as python structures.  There's no need for a json.loads to get at the data.  You could extend my example by doing json.loads(json_str) at the end, but the output would be the same as python_doc.